# Modifying template based on record saving

Tags: ember.js

I have a form and handle the submit code in my router. My template has this:

```
    {{#if isSaving}}
        Saving...
    {{else}}
    <form>
         inputs...
    </form>
    {{/if}}
```

My code for saving within the router is this (ctrl is controller):

```
events: {
    saveCompany: function(record, ctrl){
        if (!record.get('isDirty')) return;
        ctrl.set('isSaving', true);
        record.one('didUpdate', this, function() {
            ctrl.set('isSaving', false);
        });
        record.get('transaction').commit();
    },
```

When user clicks submit, "Saving..." is properly shown and hidden when update is done. But I already handle didCreate, DidUpdate etc. in my model definition - by showing some popups, but I still want to be able to prevent the user from fiddling with my form while data is being saved, that's why I use "record.one(...)". What would be best way to do so in a more "generic" way than the way I did it?

Comment: Why don't you just bind the controller to `isSaving` on the record?

Comment: I tried adding "isSavingBinding: 'content.isSaving'" to my Controller but I get " Cannot delegate set('isSaving', ) to the 'content' ... undefined". Controller's content is bound with "contentBinding: 'controllers.companies.firstObject',". Ideas?

Comment: Oh I got it, had to explicitly set "isSaving" on controller first. Thanks

Comment: How was your existing code not throwing that same error? Also, if your controller is an ObjectController you can already observe 'isSaving' on the controller without any additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller is an `Ember.ObjectController` you already have access, transparently, to the properties on the `content`. If the `content` is the record you're observing, you can just observe `isSaving` on the controller without any additional code, bindings, or what have you.